# Kotlin Make a long list a bit shorter

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to generate a list with several values ​​that add up to the total value. The list works properly, but I still want to ask if there are possibilities to optimize this better. I have tried several attempts with different functionalities but unfortunately this does not give the exact result.

I don't need the exact solution just a step in the right direction will help me a lot.

This is how the code looks right now.

```
fun getTotal(amps:List<Int>): MutableMap<Int, Int>{

    val listEqual = mutableMapOf<Int,Int>()

    if(amps.size > 8) {
        listEqual[0] = listOf(
            amps[0],
            amps[1],
            amps[2],
            amps[3],
            amps[4],
            amps[5],
            amps[6],
            amps[7],
            amps[8],
            amps[9]
        ).sum()
        if(amps.size > 18) {
            listEqual[1] = listOf(
                amps[10],
                amps[11],
                amps[12],
                amps[13],
                amps[14],
                amps[15],
                amps[16],
                amps[17],
                amps[18],
                amps[19]
            ).sum()
            if(amps.size > 28) {
                listEqual[2] = listOf(
                    amps[20],
                    amps[21],
                    amps[22],
                    amps[23],
                    amps[24],
                    amps[25],
                    amps[26],
                    amps[27],
                    amps[28],
                    amps[29]
                ).sum()
                if(amps.size > 38) {
                    listEqual[3] = listOf(
                        amps[30],
                        amps[31],
                        amps[32],
                        amps[33],
                        amps[34],
                        amps[35],
                        amps[36],
                        amps[37],
                        amps[38],
                        amps[39]
                    ).sum()
                    if(amps.size > 47) {
                        listEqual[4] = listOf(
                            amps[40],
                            amps[41],
                            amps[42],
                            amps[43],
                            amps[44],
                            amps[45],
                            amps[46],
                            amps[47],
                            amps[48]
                        ).sum()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return listEqual
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
fun getTotal(amps: List<Int>): Map<Int, Int> {
  return amps
    .windowed(10, 10, true)
    .mapIndexed { index: Int, ints: List<Int> -> index to ints.sum() }
    .toMap()
}
```

The part with *windowed()* looks likes this with named arguments:

```
    .windowed(size = 10, step = 10, partialWindows = true)
```

It 'slides' over a list by *step* and returns *size* elements. If *partialWindows* is set to true, the last part, if less than *size*, will be returned too, if set to false, it will be omitted.

Comment: @lukasJ Thanks for your message, this is by far the best answer. Thank you. Will delve further into this.

Answer (score 1):

The sizes you are checking seem arbitrary. Like if the input size is 9, it would crash at `amps[9]`. You should be checking `>=` multiples of 10 in your if statement since you are grouping chunks of 10.

Also, there doesn't seem much point in using a Map where the keys are consecutive Ints starting from 0. It might as well be a List. If you can return a List, your whole function could be:

```
return amps.chunked(10, Iterable<Int>::sum)
```

If you do need a Map, you can do

```
return amps.chunked(10, Iterable<Int>::sum)
    .mapIndexed { i, list -> i to list }
    .toMap()
```

If you need the option of dropping the last group if it's smaller than 10, then the other answer with `windowed` is more appropriate.

If `chunked` and `windowed` were not available, your code could be shortened using the `subList()` function and a loop. For example:

```
fun getTotal(amps:List<Int>): MutableMap<Int, Int>{
    val listEqual = mutableMapOf<Int,Int>()
    repeat(5) { chunkIndex ->
        if (amps.size >= chunkIndex * 10 + 10) {
            listEqual[chunkIndex] = amps.subList(chunkIndex * 10, chunkIndex * 10 + 10).sum()
        }
    }
    return listEqual
}
```

Comment: Oops, thank you! @lukas.j